# Selecting a 10 minute time chunk in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I'm new to dealing with time-series data/pandas in python. The data in question relates to some physiological data sampled every second.

I have a pandas dataframe (called df_baseline) indexed using datetime which has a frequency of one row every second for about 25 minutes.

e.g.

2016-01-22 14:39:05

```
2016-01-22 14:35:06

2016-01-22 14:35:07

type(df_baseline.index)
Out[21]: pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

Data for this project was collected at varying times and dates with start and stop points varying and I want to iterate through several of such files picking up the first 10 minutes of this data and creating averages and other statistics.

I have searched and am getting confused with datetimes, timeseries, periods and timedeltas but the solutions I've found relate to selecting between very specific time ranges using things like df.between_time and such like which I Don't have as each datafile .

Am I approaching this the wrong way? I feel like the solution is staring me in the face. Please get me on the right track!

Comment: Why not perform statistics on your dataframe every 600 rows (seen as each row is 1 second?). you can write a function to select for every 600 rows do something.

Comment: Many thanks Joey, This should make things much easier and will certainly do the job. As i thought...I need to change the way i needed to think about the problem!

Comment: Out of interest however, is there a way does any one know, where you can tell pandas to select time based on the time index without being so specific?